# Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage.Type' to expected argument type 'UIImage'

Tags: swift, swiftui

It may be a beginner question :). Why do I get this error? "Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage.Type' to expected argument type 'UIImage'"

I don't know why! I have reviewed the code over and over again but no luck!

I am using Xcode version 13.1 and swiftui.

How can I solve this ?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    @Binding var pickedImage: Image
    @Binding var showImagePicker: Bool
    @Binding var ImageData: Data
    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePicker.Coordinator{
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context)  -> UIImagePickerController{
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        return picker
    }        
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context){
        
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
        var parent: ImagePicker
        init( parent: ImagePicker){
            self.parent = parent
        }
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
            let uiImage = info[.editedImage] as! UIImage
            parent.pickedImage = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            if let mediaData = uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5){
                parent.ImageData = mediaData
            }
            parent.showImagePicker = false
        } 
    }  
}
```

I get the error here

```
parent.pickedImage = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
```

Comment: This code compiles for me.  Are you sure this is the code producing the error?  You might consider choosing Clean Build Folder from the Product menu in Xcode and then building again.

Comment: Please take a look at the code I provided on your other question. Originally, you had UIImage (the type) not uiImage (the variable). I address this and other errors.

Comment: That would most certainly cause the issue.

Comment: Oh, now I see that you deleted the other question, along with my answer. That's a shame when someone takes the time to answer one of your questions.

Comment: @jnpdx brother I deleted the question before you answer it! When I found that I have typos error I said it's a useless question so I deleted it. Sorry if it took you time to answer it. I edited the code and I get the above error! Sorry again.

Comment: @CharlesA. Yes this the code that produce the error

Comment: No, you deleted it after I answered. It is not possible to answer a deleted question.

Comment: @sultan.h This code as written works for me.  Perhaps you should copy it from this post and try again?